# Finding a homomorphism from a polynomial to matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

I have to show that $$R_k\cong\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2-k)$$
for $R_k=
  \left\{\left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   kb & a \\
  \end{array} } \right)\ \middle| \ a,b\in \mathbb{Z} \right\}
, k\in\mathbb{Z}$

I know I have to find an homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z}[X] \rightarrow R_k$ such that $ker(\phi) = (X^2-k)$ and that $\phi$ needs to be surjective.

I think I need to do something with the fact that the ideal $(X^2-k)$ is the $0$ matrix in $R_k$. But I don't know how to construct this homomorphism. Does someone have any tips?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2720817/using-the-first-isomorphism-theorem-to-prove-that-s-is-a-subring-of-m-2-math

Answer (score 1):

You won't get anywhere, because your matrix is wrong. I supsect that you meant $\begin{pmatrix}a & b \cr kb & a\end{pmatrix}$.

You need to find a surjective ring morphism $f:\mathbb{Z}[X]\to R_k$ such that $f(X^2-k)=0$, and apply the first isomorphism theorem.

Since $f $is a ring morphism $f(1)=1$, and then $f(-1)=-1$. You can deduce easily that $f(k)=k I_2$. (You may also use the fact that there is only one ring morphism form $\mathbb{Z}$ to any ring, if you prefer).

Then your matrix $M=f(X)\in R_k$ needs to satisfy $M^2=kI_2$, since $f(X^2-k)=0$

Don't you see a matrix in $R_k$ which satisfies that ?

If you still don't see, you could apply Cayley Hamilton to your $2\times 2$ matrix to have a educated guess...